# Physics2D.Raycast is not working, even With Collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Physics2D.Raycast is not working on my script, it should be true after colliding with an object but it doesnt work, i used debug.ray to see if the raycast touched the object and it did but the script did nothing, the object it should touch has a box collider2d and has the right layer.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Speed;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    private StartLevel StartLevelScript;

    public LayerMask Blocks;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rb.freezeRotation = true;
        rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePosition;
        StartLevelScript = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("StartLevel").GetComponent<StartLevel>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (StartLevelScript.LevelStarted == true)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(Speed, rb.velocity.y);
            rb.freezeRotation = false;
            rb.constraints &= ~RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePosition;
        }
        else
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
            rb.freezeRotation = true;
            rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePosition;
        }

        //This Is Not Working
        if (Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, new Vector2(-1, 0), 1, Blocks) || Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, new Vector2(1, 0), 1, Blocks))
        {
            print(1);
            Speed *= -Speed;
            print(2);
        }
    }
}
```

i don't know what to do, i would like some help, feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: I'm Just Stupid i needed to add a value

Comment: Yeah, I'm guessing the `Speed *= -Speed`? I do wish people would stop voting perfectly reasonable questions like this down! +1